# typings install throws an error

Tags: npm, angular

I tried to start the Angular2 Quickstart Demo (https://angular.io/guide/quickstart) but i am getting an error at this point:

```
typings install
```

I am getting this:

```
 $ typings install
typings ERR! message an HTTP(S) proxy server `host` and `port` must be specified!

typings ERR! cwd /Users/mschakulat/stuff/spielwiese/Angular2/Test
typings ERR! system Darwin 14.5.0
typings ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/iterator/.npm-packages/bin/typings" "install"
typings ERR! node -v v5.9.0
typings ERR! typings -v 0.7.9

typings ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
typings ERR!   <https://github.com/typings/typings/issues>
```

Maybe anyone has an idea whats going on here?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: No, i am not. But i found out, that it works, if i try the same command with sudo. No idea why it only works as root?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had this issue and my resolution was to unset any proxy environment variables that were set with empty values.

E.g.:

```
env | grep proxy
http_proxy=
ftp_proxy=
unset http_proxy ftp_proxy
```

After that, my typings install worked without a sudo.  Sudo was causing other issues, like folders owned by root and not write accessible...

Comment: I also had to unset https_proxy

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to open a new Terminal window for the changes to take effect.